# Question about polynomial multiplication

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let $f=\sum a_{j}x^{j}$ and $g=\sum b_{j}x^{j}$ be two nonzero polynomials with coefficients in some field. Fix a natural number $i \in [0, \deg f]$. I want to know if the following is true:

There exists $n\in [i, i+deg(g)]$ such that the coefficient $c_{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n} a_{k}b_{n-k}$ of $fg$ is nonzero.

Note: this question is NOT asking whether $fg=0$.

Comment: Well, certainly $k=i$ for some $k$ as $k$ runs from $0$ to $n$, right? So the question is just: Does $fg=0$ imply $f=0\lor g=0$, i.e., does $F[x]$ have zero-divisors?

Comment: The leading coefficient cannot be $0$ because in a field , there are no zero-divisors.

Comment: I think there is some confusion about the question.  Let me try to elaborate...

Comment: $i$ is fixed, so maybe I shouldn't have used $i$ as the dummy variable for $f$.

Comment: So $a_{i}$ doesn't need to occur in the multiplication of the leading term.

Comment: It is not true that for all $n$, $k=i$ for some $k$ between $0$ and $n$, right?

Comment: My question is not about leading coefficients.

Comment: How do you distinguish between "not every coefficient of $fg$ is zero" and "$fg$ is not the zero polynomial"? You insist that you're asking the former but NOT the latter -- but those are completely synonymous statements.

Comment: @HenningMakholm it says "not every coefficient of fg WHERE $k=i$ FOR SOME $k$ is not zero".  The $i$ is fixed and is not part of the definition of $c_{n}$

Comment: -1: What in the world does "not every coefficient $\sum_{k=0}^n a_k b_{n-k}$ where $k=i$ for some $i$ is zero" even mean? The sum is over all values of $k$ from $0$ to $n$, so you can't say "where $k=i$ for some $i$" after it...

Comment: @barto you seem to understand what I am asking, could you suggest a better way for me to phrase it?

Comment: Whats hard to understand?  I am asking if there is some coefficient of fg, involving a fixed ai, which is non-zero?

Comment: But each coefficient of $f(x)g(x)$ involves multiple $a_i$s, so what do you mean by "fixed $a_i$"?

Comment: $i$ is fixed between 0 and deg(f)

Comment: i did not use $i$ in my definition of the polynomial multiplication, you are falsely assuming that.

Comment: I rewrote the question; feel free to undo if I changed the meaning.

Comment: @barto: I think he meant: There exists an $n$ such that $i \le n \le i+\operatorname{deg} g$, where $c_n$ is nonzero.

Comment: @SihOASHoihd Do you require $n$ to satisfy $i \le n \le i+\operatorname{deg} g$ as Henning Makholm said?

Comment: If your question has no restriction on $n$, then Henning Makholm's answer is wrong because with $i=3$, we have $c_9\neq0$.

Comment: It was a simple question not worth this level of scrutiny.

Comment: Removing my downvote after the recent edit. The problem was that when you try and formulate the question precisely, you need to be really precise. Practitioners of math are bound to take it literally. If you are a bit more vague to begin with, only then our "autocomplete" logic kicks in :-). Obviously Henning spent a while figuring out what you must have meant for the question to make sense. Some of us proud of our autocomplete routines. My experience is that when I use mine, it is not always appreciated by others. You got it "almost" right, throwing people off the rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ (x^8+x^7+x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)(x-1) = x^9-1 $$
Let your $i$ be, for example, $3$.

Comment: Ah, thank you.  I thought about this, but I should have thought about it more.

Comment: So isn't this an example where $n\ge i$ does exist? Namely, with $i=3$, the coefficient of $x^i$ is nonzero in $f$, but also with $n=9$ (which is indeed $\ge i$), the coefficient of $x^9$ i the product is nonzero.

Comment: I think this answer is for the stronger requirement $i \leq n \leq i + \deg g$; which is one way to interpret the question.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: The $n\ge i$ in the question came in with barto's edit -- this answer is based on a different interpretation of the (not entirely optimally clear) comments the OP made.

Comment: And the point (of my guess at what the question means) would be that the product polynomial can be written as $$ (a_8b_1)x^9 + (a_8b_0+a_7b_1)x^8+(a_7b_0+a_6b_1)x^7 + \cdots + (a_1b_0+a_0b_1)x + (a_0b_0) $$ and the question was whether all of the coefficients whose expression _in this form_ involves $a_3$ can be zero at the same time.

Comment: $n\geq i$ is not sufficient to insure that $a_{i}$ is part of the multiplication of $c_{n}$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm yes, my idea was that we are thinking about these polynomials rather formally

Comment: So how to rewrite the question?  Nobody liked it when I wrote "there exists $n$ such that the coefficient $c_{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n} a_{k}b_{n-k}$ of $fg$ where $k=i$ for some $k$ is nonzero."

Comment: @SihOASHoihd In Henning's last comment, he suggested you were asking if it was possible for all coefficients $c_n$ involving $f$'s $i$th term $a_i$ (equivalently, $i\le n\le i+\deg g$) to be zero. You responded to that with "yes." However, that is unclear from the original sentence you wrote, "there exists an $n$ such that $c_n=\sum_{k=0}^n a_kb_{n-k}$ is nonzero and $k=i$ for some $i$," because you simply **cannot** write "$k=i$ for some $i$" right after a summation with dummy variable $k$. It makes no sense, and doesn't communicate you're focusing on $c_n$'s that have $a_i$ in them.

Answer (score 2):

Why, yes, since for any polynomial ring over an integral domain, the leading term of $fg$ is the product of the leading terms of $f$ and $g$, and hence $\deg(fg)=\deg f+\deg g$.

Comment: I am – thoughtful. What's always not clear is ‘k=i for some $k$’ (k is a dummy variable).

Comment: @SihOASHoihd You're asking if not every coefficient of $f(x)g(x)$ is zero, and this answer points out that the leading coefficient of $f(x)g(x)$ is not zero. So it answers your question, no?

Comment: Do you mean there is some coefficient of $fg$, involving a fixed $a_i$, which is non-zero?